# Enter Website URL and it doesn't do anything for (many) seconds. Is this my server/host?

Tags: pagespeed

I have a basic web plan with GoDaddy for a website I built for a client: https://www.meetjaycee.com/

I've built quite a few websites, but they all have better than basic hosting plans and none of them experience this particular issue.

**The Issue**
When you type in https://www.meetjaycee.com/ the browser more often than not delay loading the page or site for many seconds. If I'm on Google for example, I will put in the URL to the website, but will sit on Google's home page for nearly 3-6 seconds before the browser switches over and even begins to do a first paint on the website.

I've noticed this issue doesn't happen if I refresh the page while on it (loads quickly), and sometimes doesn't seem to be an issue on Firefox.

**SPEED TESTS**
I have an "A" and a "B" in GTMetrix for this site.

Pingdom is 75% (which is better than many sites I have that load immediately)

Google Insights has 55 (also better than sites I have that load immediately with lesser scores)

Yet none of the issues they're complaining about are things that would have been loaded or known yet because the delay happens before the browser even goes to the website.

Any insight on what's going on, or if there's a tool out there that can help diagnose where this pre-lag is from would be GREATLY appreciated.

Thanks all!

Comment: GoDaddy and other "basic" hosts load up hundreds of sites on a server.  They all fight for the CPU and bandwidth.  There might also be startup time the first time the site is accessed that day.   F12 developer tools in Chrome has some timing info that might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is checking with GoDaddy support. The plan the domain is on is going to matter. It might be shared hosting. If this is the case perhaps you could ask for the domain to be moved to a different IP, there might be a data hog in the shared hosting causing the slowness. When I visited the site, it loads instantly for me using Chrome (I am on 120 mb/sec connection). I also googled it and loaded that way, same load time. Seemed reasonable to me, but it might vary throughout the day depending on traffic if the hosting is shared on the same server as other godaddy clients.

Lastly I see the head is jammed full of things (123 lines of CSS/scripts/DNS-prefetches). See what you can do to move down some of your scripts to the bottom of the  This should help with load time. I understand you may not be able to move it all, but you should be able to move some. Also consider eliminating so many things in the head.

Without having seen any hints to what you think might be causing the issue, or code to pinpoint to... I'm afraid all we can do is speculate. So yeah, start with GoDaddy support.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I'll head over to GoDaddy and see about moving to another IP. Appreciate the insight!